# Can't change str to int inside a function

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, type-conversion, int

```
def Validation(digits):
    while not digits.isdigit():
        digits = input("Please select an interger for this part")
    digits = int(digits)

length_1 = input("What is the length of one of the sides?")
    Validation(length_1)
length_2 = input("What is the length of another side?")
    Validation(length_2)
answer = length_1 * length_2 / 2
```

I am attempting to use a function which validates the users inputs. At the end it should turn it into an interger so that they can be multiplied together. However, I get the error:
answer = length_1 * length_2 / 2
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'. I can fix it by adding int(length_1) and int(length_2), however the point of the function was to not do this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html. Your function can't modify what `length_1` refers to by reassigning to `digits`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the value from the function and also replace the variable that you are going to use.

```
 def Validation(digits):
        while not digits.isdigit():
            digits = input("Please select an interger for this part")
        return int(digits)

    length_1 = input("What is the length of one of the sides?")
    length_1 = Validation(length_1)
    length_2 = input("What is the length of another side?")
    length_2 = Validation(length_2)
    answer = length_1 * length_2 / 2 
    print(answer)
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize I had to return, and forgot to reassign the value

Answer (score 1):

Python passes by value. The `digits` passed to your function is re-assigned in the last line. That does not change the original value, it just creates a new variable. Instead of what you are doing, `return int(digits)`

Answer (score 0):

`digits = int(digits)` can't alter the string passed to `Validation`. All reassigning in the function does is change what the function parameter is pointing at. That has no effect outside the function.

Just return the parsed digits:

```
def Validation(digits):
    while not digits.isdigit():
        digits = input("Please select an interger for this part")
    return int(digits)

length_1 = input("What is the length of one of the sides?")
parsed_length_1 = Validation(length_1)
```

Comment: I thought there would also be an effect outside the function. Thank you.